# Confusion over Page Object Model C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've written basic code which goes to a specific URL then changes the country and currency. I now want to tidy my code up and make it easier to maintain.

I've not used page object model before so have been reading about it. I understand the basic concepts of creating another class within the project and creating an extension to page objects that are used to initialize the web elements.

So essentially all my `FindElements` will be stored in a separate class. I've created two Classes within a PageObjects folder. HomePage and PreferencePage.

Below code is working and does exactly as I expect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.asos.com/men/");
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='country-selector-btn']")).Click();

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("country")));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(country, "India");


            IWebElement currency = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("currency")));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(currency, "$ USD");

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='save-country-button']")).Click();

            webDriver.Quit();

        }

        private static void SelectElementFromDropDown(IWebElement ele, string text)
        {
            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(ele);
            select.SelectByText(text);
        }


    }
}
```

Now I want to implement Page Object Model. I have created my main TestClass, along with a HomePage and PreferencePage class. I'm unsure of how to implement the next bit. I know my TestClass will be making a call to the HomePage for the URL and PreferencePage for the country and currency but I'm unsure how the implementation would look.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class TestClass
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        public void SetUp()
        {

            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        }

        public void ChangePreferences()
        {

            Homepage home = new Homepage(driver);
            home.goToPage();
            PreferencePage preference = home.GoToPreferencePage();
            UpdateCountry = preference.UpdateCountryPreference();
            UpdateCurrency = preference.UpdateCurrencyPreference();
            UpdatePreference = preference.PreferenceUpdated();

        }

        }
    }
```

HomePage class

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class HomePage
    {

        private IWebDriver driver;

        public HomePage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
        }

        public void goToPage()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.asos.com/men/");
        }

    }
}
```

Preference page

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise1.PageObjects
{
    class PreferencePage
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        public UpdateCountry(string text)
        {

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("country")));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(country, "India");

        }

        public void UpdateCurrency()

        {
            IWebElement currency = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("currency")));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(currency, "$ USD");
        }

        public void ClickPreference()

        {

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='save-country-button']")).Click();
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it would look like that:

```
class TestClass
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    public void SetUp()
    {
        ..
    }

    public TestChangePreferences()
    {
        //actual test
        ChangePreferences();
    }

    public void ChangePreferences()
    {
     .......
    }
}
```

I'd wrap it with a testing framework such as NUnit for better test management and tools.
this could give you a pretty good example:
https://github.com/nunit/nunit-csharp-samples/blob/master/DataDrivenTests/GenericTestFixture.cs

Comment: Yes correct, but how can I translate my current test that is working to fit into the TestChangePreference method. WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("country")));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(country, "India");

Comment: simply call TestChangePreferences() with  ChangePreferences(); inside.